# The monotone operator in $BV$ space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory

I am considering the following minimizing problem:
$$
\min_{u\in BV(\Omega)}\{\frac12\|u-u_0\|_{L^2}^2 + |u|_{TV(\Omega)}\}
$$
where $u_0\in BV(\Omega)$, $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$ is open bounded, smooth boundary.

The above problem surely has a unique minimizer $\bar u\in BV$.

Then I could write the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation for $\bar u$:
$$
\bar u - \operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla \bar u}{|\nabla \bar u|}\right) = u_0 \tag 1
$$
Next, I define the operator $A$ to be
$$
A(u):=- \operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla  u}{|\nabla  u|}\right) 
$$
I am wishing to show $A$ is a monotone operator. It is easy to see that for $v\in C_0^\infty$, that $(Av,v)\geq 0$ for sure.

My question: what should be the right domain for operator $A$? I think the domain of $A$ should somehow contain the space $BV$ since it is the E-L for minimizing function, but a $BV$ function wouldn't make sense for equation $(1)$. Maybe there are some regularity result I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\varphi:=|.|_{TV}$ is a convex and (I think) lower semicontinuous function from $L^2$ to $[0,\infty]$. Its subdifferential $\partial\varphi$ is what you need to write the Euler-Lagrange equation, in the form $\bar{u}-u_0\in\partial\varphi(\bar{u})$.

Comment: So, do you think, in your suggestion, that $A$ is an maximal monotone operator?

Comment: This is indeed classical, see e.g. the 1997 paper by Chambolle & P.L. Lions (and references therein).

Comment: $A$ has to be defined as a _set-valued_ map, not as a single-valued map as you did. Then it is maximal monotone, yes.